# Are Web Service References necessary in all project?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I currently have one Web Service in a solution of multiple projects. Since I don't want to add service references in all project to be able to use it, I have created a project with static a class named "ServiceHelper" for the moment. This project would be the only one with the service references and the helper would do all the request ncessary. The Web Service is set public (not internal).

My problem here is that when I initialize my SoapClient in my helper from another project that do not have the service references, it throws an exception. But when I add the service reference to that other project, it works. Is it normal or not?

The exception throwed translated (because it is said in French) is :
Unable to find an element endpoint default refers to the contract 'ServiceReference.WebServiceSoap' section in the ServiceModel client configuration. This may be due to the fact that the configuration file of your application is not found or the endpoint element matching this contract is found in the client element

Is there something missing in my config file? because I didn't change anything in the 2 projects mentionned.

Exemple of how I initialize my SoapClient in my helper :

```
private static ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient _webService = new ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient();
```

Comment: It is obviously the problem with the missing sections in the app.config for the second project. Compare the configurations and I am sure you will notice what is missing. Keep in mind that in order to avoid the configuration problem this might turn useful to make your ServiceHelper be independent from the app.config. If your "clients" and your "service" are local to your project you could build all the necessary configuration (binding etc) from code.

Comment: I didn't know that you had to add the necessary sections in your configuration file in the client projects so it would go to the helper. I have copied what was in my helper project's config file that was referencing to the Web Service into the one of the client project without adding the service reference and it works now. I will surely try to put it in my code instead to not have to do that anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on with @zverev.eugene, you don't need the references in every project, but the web.config or app.config in the project is where the connection and configuration information is retrieved from. This is because the application calling your class library is what supplies all configuration information (e.g., if you have a data access layer in a class library, the connection string would come from the .config of the application calling the DAL, not the class library itself).